# How to do a query with one specific date

Tags: apex, soql, query, date, date-literals

I want to do a query that excludes today and yesterday. I tried to do it in this way:

```
CreatedDate != today 
AND CreatedDate != yesterday
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but check whether `LAST_N_DAYS:2` can help you. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the console (SOQL) you can say

```
CreatedDate < YESTERDAY
```

e.g. Querying account

```
select count(id)
from account
where createddate < YESTERDAY
```

This will return the number of accounts created excluding those created yesterday or today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it on apex you can use some structure similar to this:

```
Set<Date> Dates; // You will need to populate this with the values you want to exclude
Dates.add(System.today);
Dates.add(System.today.addDays(-1));
```

Where you can store all the dates you want to exclude and your query would end up looking something like

```
SELECT ___ FROM ____ WHERE NOT(CreatedDate in: Dates)
```

This way is more flexble if you start wanting add more values to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

- For Today you can use `Date.today()`
- For yesterdays date you can use addDays() method. Example`Date.today().addDays(-1)`

Comment: thank you, but i am using for now the  query editor in the developer console, there is one other way yet?